# Writing and reading CSV file in C wierd output

Tags: c, csv, printf

I'm new to C language and I'm trying to save data to a .csv and read the same data in a very simple program.

```
    char c;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("file.csv", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "Hello;World\nLine");
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    while (getc(fp) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", getc(fp));
    }

    fclose(fp);
```

I don't know why the output is wrong:

```
el;ol
ie
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `getc(fp) != EOF` : This discard in the input character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are reading a character in the loop condition (so it prints out every other one when printing), and reading another one when printing it out. Try this:

```
int ch;
while ((ch=getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", ch);
}
```

Comment: To compare with EOF, `int ch;` instead of `char ch;`

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
while (getc(fp) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", getc(fp));
}
```

You are calling `getc()` twice every time through the loop, but only printing one character.  So you get half te hrces rm te fl n ls h ohr hl.